# Batch FOR loop to look up for a file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a Batch file that I run and I wait for a file to be written up in the directory. Currently I have a PAUSE command and once the file is there I just press a key and the rest of the batch goes on.

I would like to replace that PAUSE with a FOR loop that looks up the file is there and automatically runs the rest of the batch once the file gets there

This is the section

```
echo Make sure TEST file is ready
PAUSE
ren *.csv test.csv
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the file that's been written in that folder is a csv file with a random name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) cannot wait for  file to exist.

You could use a [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) loop and an [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) clause to jump back conditionally if no matching file exists. Make sure to insert a delay in the loop (e. g., [`timeout`](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)) to not heavily load the CPU:

```cmd
:LOOP
> nul timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
if not exist "*.csv" goto :LOOP
ren "*.csv" "test.csv"
```

In case there could also be a directory with a matching name, you could use [`dir /A:-D`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to search for matching files only, together with the [conditional operator `||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
:LOOP
> nul timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
> nul 2>&1 dir /A:-D "*.csv" || goto :LOOP
ren "*.csv" "test.csv"
```